# powershell create ini file remotely

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script to create an ini file via powershell to disable windows UAC.

```
$functionText = @"`[Options`]
UpdateKey=04/28/2015 12:50:27 AM
WINDOW_LEFT=258
WINDOW_TOP=149
WINDOW_WIDTH=666
WINDOW_HEIGHT=519
WINDOW_MAX=0
BackupDir=C:\Windows\System32
UpdateCheck=1
Language=1033
(App)Sun Java=False
NewVersion=5.05.5176
SkipUAC=1
FinderInclude1=PATH|C:\|*.*|RECURSE
FinderInclude2=PATH|D:\|*.*|RECURSE
FinderIncludeStates=1|1
I see SkipUAC=1
ShowCleanWarning=False
ShowFirefoxCleanWarning=False
WipeFreeSpaceDrives=C:\
RunICS=0
CookiesToSave=*.piriform.com|google.com
"@

New-Item c:\Program Files\Ccleaner\Ccleaner.ini -type file -force -value $functionText
```

I keep getting Unrecognized token in source text.
At C:\PROGRA~3\BEANYW~1\Scripts\2480_C~1\~SC52F~1.PS1:1 char:17
+ $functionText =  <<<< @"`[Options`]
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken

I tried adding the escape character around options to see if that would do it - I think the issue is around the word [options]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a here-string, put the @" on a line by itself.

```
$functionText = @"
[Options]
UpdateKey=04/28/2015 12:50:27 AM
WINDOW_LEFT=258
WINDOW_TOP=149
WINDOW_WIDTH=666
WINDOW_HEIGHT=519
WINDOW_MAX=0
BackupDir=C:\Windows\System32
UpdateCheck=1
Language=1033
(App)Sun Java=False
NewVersion=5.05.5176
SkipUAC=1
FinderInclude1=PATH|C:\|*.*|RECURSE
FinderInclude2=PATH|D:\|*.*|RECURSE
FinderIncludeStates=1|1
I see SkipUAC=1
ShowCleanWarning=False
ShowFirefoxCleanWarning=False
WipeFreeSpaceDrives=C:\
RunICS=0
CookiesToSave=*.piriform.com|google.com
"@

New-Item "C:\Program Files\Ccleaner\Ccleaner.ini" -type file -force -value $functionText
```

The advantage of a here-string is that you don't have to escape anything inside the string. So if there were single or double quotes it wouldn't matter. As long as the literal string '"@' doesn't exist, on a line by itself, inside the ini file code you're safe.

Read [more about here-strings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx).

Also, as shown in the sample above, you need to put quotes around the file path.

Comment: Now i get this error New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Files\
Ccleaner\Ccleaner.ini'.
At C:\PROGRA~3\BEANYW~1\Scripts\2483_0~1\~SC9FB~1.PS1:26 char:9
+ New-Item <<<<  c:\Program Files\Ccleaner\Ccleaner.ini -type file -force -valu
e $functionText
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindin 
   gException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.NewItemCommand

Comment: Put quotes around the path. New-Item "c:\Program Files\Ccleaner\Ccleaner.ini" -type file -force -value $functionText

Comment: Fixed - it just needed "c:\Program Files\Ccleaner\Ccleaner.ini" around